# Display sum of Amount corresponding to some column xyz

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, mysql, distinct

I had created model donation to save donation information and now i want to display total amount of donation to be shown with all the other field

my table is as follows

`---------------------------
  name address phone amount
  test   abc   454545  55
  test2  pqr   83294   10
  test   abc   31286   50`

and desires output would be like

`---------------------------
  name address phone amount
  test   abc   454545  105
  test2  pqr   83294   10`

i'm trying to put code

`$testmodel = Mage::getModel('donation/donation')
                ->getCollection()
                ->getSelect()->group('name')
                ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('SUM({{amount}})', 'amount');`

but it can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used this query to get desired output

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$categoryProductTable=$read->getTableName('donation');
$select = $read->select()->from(array('cp'=>$categoryProductTable),array('sum(amount) as sum', 'name', 'address' ,'phone'));
$select->group('name');
$products=$read->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` is only available as a method for the resource model. Since you've appended it after `getSelect` it wont be able to find the method.

```
$testmodel = Mage::getModel('donation/donation')->getCollection()
   ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('SUM(`amount`)', 'amount')
   ->getSelect()->group('name');
```

Try above, that should work better

Comment: it didn't work I have to perform it using Zend Query